# Initializing pandas dataframes with and without index,columns yields different results

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

If I use the following methodology to construct a `pandas.DataFrame`, I get an output that (I think) is peculiar:

```
import pandas, numpy

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    numpy.random.rand(100,2), index = numpy.arange(100), columns = ['s1','s2'])
smoothed = pandas.DataFrame(
    pandas.ewma(df, span = 21), index = df.index, columns = ['smooth1','smooth2'])
```

When I go to look at the smoothed values, I get:

```
>>> smoothed.tail()
smooth1  smooth2
95      NaN      NaN
96      NaN      NaN
97      NaN      NaN
98      NaN      NaN
99      NaN      NaN
```

This seems like it an aggregation of the following fragmented calls, which yield different results:

```
smoothed2 = pandas.DataFrame(pandas.ewma(df, span = 21))
smoothed2.index = df.index
smoothed2.columns = ['smooth1','smooth2']
```

Again using the `DataFrame.tail()` invocation I get:

```
>>> smoothed2.tail()
smooth1   smooth2
95  0.496021  0.501153 
96  0.506118  0.507541
97  0.516655  0.544621
98  0.520212  0.543751
99  0.518170  0.572429
```

Can anyone provide rationale as to why these to DataFrame construction methodologies should be different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of `ewma(df, span=21)` is already a DataFrame, so when you pass it to the DataFrame constructor along with a list of columns, it "selects" out the columns that you passed. It's difficult in this particular case to break the link between label and data. If you had done instead:

```
In [23]: smoothed = DataFrame(ewma(df, span = 21).values, index=df.index, columns = ['smooth1','smooth2'])
In [24]: smoothed.head()
Out[24]: 
    smooth1   smooth2
0  0.218350  0.877693
1  0.400214  0.813499
2  0.308564  0.739426
3  0.433341  0.641891
4  0.525260  0.620541
```

that is no problem. of course

```
smoothed = ewma(df, span=21)
smoothed.columns = ['smooth1', 'smooth2']
```

is perfectly fine too

Comment: Wes, you're amazing. Thanks for building such an amazing piece of abstraction and thanks for such a prompt response!